# jQuery-ui selectable doesn't work properly on a bootstrap 3 modal

Tags: jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, jquery-ui-selectable

When I am trying to drag the mouse over the selectable items the rectangle that should be drawn by drag action is drawn under the bootstrap modal like its z index is lower than the modals'.

When I past the code to a angular component everything works fine. I want it to act the same for bootstrap modal.

I'm guessing that bootstrap css causing this behavior, what changes should I do in the boostrap/jquery-ui css if this is the case?

**Edit**

I found the css class `ui-selectable-helper` in the `jquery-ui.structure.css` file. If i change the z-index to a big number it is working as I wanted. But i want to change the css from my component and not from the `jquery-ui.structure.min.css` file. I tried to override the class in my component css but with no luck. Is there a way to change the css inside the component?

Code for the unwanted behavior: (the rectangle is under the bootstrap modal)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #feedback { font-size: 1.4em; }
  #selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
  #selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
  #selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 450px; }
  #selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 100px; height: 80px; font-size: 4em; text-align: center; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body container">
          <ol id="selectable">
            <li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">4</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">5</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">6</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">7</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">8</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">9</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">10</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">11</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">12</li>
          </ol>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Code With the wanted behavior:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #feedback { font-size: 1.4em; }
  #selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
  #selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
  #selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 450px; }
  #selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 100px; height: 80px; font-size: 4em; text-align: center; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

  <ol id="selectable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">6</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">7</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">8</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">9</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">10</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">11</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">12</li>
  </ol>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```